# how to split Text file data into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files, data-extraction

I have a newbie question regarding pandas.

I have a log file(.txt file) with  following contents with numerous similar lines :-

```
*2021-11-15 10:00:00,458 - DEBUG - ThreadID: 140033633835712; Class: Controller; Method: _cycleHit; Line: 182; Comment: Start

2021-11-15 10:00:00,458 - DEBUG - ThreadID: 140033365366528; Class: RemoteInterface; Method: InterfaceCycleHit; Line: 281; Comment: Start*
```

---

##### I want a data frame in a following manner --> [Dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hryCn.png)

---

I am a newbie.
I will be grateful for any help I get.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your irregular application, a quick and dirty import is as follows but be careful regarding the replacement of ";" since comments may contain and might be important given the context. If so, try to improve the code by eliminating only the end of line ";".

Edit log file for multi word comments:

```
file = open('log.txt', "r")
list_of_lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for i in range(len(list_of_lines)):
    comment_index = list_of_lines[i].find('Comment:')
    list_of_lines[i] = list_of_lines[i][:comment_index+9] + list_of_lines[i][comment_index+9:].replace(' ', '_')

file = open('log2.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(list_of_lines)
file.close()
```

Read as CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv('log2.txt', delim_whitespace = True, header = None)
df = df.drop([2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11 , 13], axis=1)
for col in [6, 8, 10, 12, 14]: df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace(';', ''))
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Type', 'Thread ID', 'Class', 'Method', 'Line', 'Comment']
df['Comment'] = df.Comment.apply(lambda  x: x.replace('_', ' '))
```

Comment: Hello Slybot, thank you for the comment.

I tried your code, bit I am getting the following error ---

"ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 15 fields in line 4, saw 18"

Comment: This error is possibly due to multi word comments since my quick solution assumes single word comments. To fix it, simple read file, adjust the comment spaces to underscore, write a new file and read that one. Then fix the underscore within the data frame for the comment column. See the edited code.

Comment: This worked mate!

Thank you for your help, really grateful.

Cheers.

P.s - just needed to change x as str(x), as x is a float object.
(adding the above sentence for anybody who uses your (Slybot) code :) )